# Is thre any way to integrate ejs file in angular 5 instead of html file?

Tags: angular

I want to set in EJS Rendering, so that the directive magic should happens on UI when it is render.

The problem here is coming that EJS is not allowing to put angular Directives in its format. Is their any possible way for this.

Angular 5 in EJS file while rendering that Template from Node JS.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use server side templates with Angular 2+. Templates need to be ready at build time. You can retrieve HTML via XHR and render that inside a template, ie `<div [innerHTML]="htmlFromServer">` but that HTML will not be compiled, ie. it can't host other Angular components or directives.

AngularJS 1.x would be better suited for that use case, it's all compiled at runtime.